# Estimating parameters of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, linear-regression

Suppose I have the following equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}  = (a+bx)y $$

If I am given data concerning $y$ i.e. $(t_i, y(t_i))$ and $x_i$, how can I get estimates for the parameters $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Without any boundary conditions, strictly speaking you cannot. You would be forced to take the boundary condition (at an arbitrarily chosen point) as a *third* fitting parameter.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate both sides
$$y(t)-y(0)=a\int_0^t y(\tau) d\tau  + b\int_0^t x(\tau) y(\tau) d\tau $$
By [trapezoidal integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), calculate the functions 
$$F(t_i)=\int_0^{t_i} y(\tau) d\tau $$
$$G(t_i)=\int_0^{t_i} x(\tau) y(\tau) d\tau $$
numerically from your data.

Now solve the [linear least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics))
$$y(t_i)-y(0)=aF(t_i) + bG(t_i) $$
for $a,b$.

($y(0)$ here is the third parameter / boundary condition of which Ian speaks in a comment. You might already know it from your input data, or you can get it as a third solution of the least-squares problem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would the approach change for instance if $a+bx$ is replaced by say $a\exp(bx)$?

Comment: That would be trickier, because it can no longer be easily reduced to a linear problem.

Comment: @Wouter If the coefficient is $f(t)$ then it is still a linear problem...

Comment: @Ian $dy/dt=(a+bx)y$ is linear in $a,b$, but $dy/dt=a \exp(b x) y$ is not.